# Request url without pagination django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination

All my sistem has pagination. I want request a single url without pagination, but as a request param, not in my remove in my application, because sometimes I want with pagination and sometimes without.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you please provide some more data about how you paginate your responses?

Comment: this is will be base on some condition

Answer (score 0):

I did not get your question in 100%

But I think I can make you clear.

You can remove your pagination from your view if you do not using `paginate_queryset` method, specifically such classes as `ModelViewSet` or `ReadOnlyViewSet`, `ListCreateAPIView`, `ListAPIView`, `ListModelMixin`

You can use `APIView` or `GenericAPIView` and define get method and there put your logic without pagination

Answer (score 0):

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    if (queryset some condition):  # here you can send data without paginate or in else it will automatically paginate the result
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:    
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```